# Schema.ini not giving data after " (double quotes) from a csv file

Tags: csv

Trying to parse a CSV file using schema. File contains info like

```
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4" GRAY TIP DRILL,K125746
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4" GRAY TIP DRILL,K127188
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4" GRAY TIP DRILL,K127960
```

For some reasons I am not getting data after " (double quotes) e.g.

```
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4
N,5800-4-125,1/8 .125 X 4
```

I am reading this CSV file using `ACE OLEDB.12` data provider.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try in schema.ini:

```
TextDelimiter=none
```